# How to convert a maven plugin to a leiningen one

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, hapi-fhir

Hi I am trying to add the hapi-fhir library to a clojure project.
Does anyone now how to add the tender plugin entry : http://hapifhir.io/doc_tinder.html  in the project.clj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details you provided and assuming you have the associated jar file
in your local .m2 repository, you should be able to just add

[ca.uhn.hapi.fhir/hapi-tinder-plugin "2.3-SNAPSHOT"]

However, if you do not have the library in your local .m2 or for some reason,
you cannot get that to work, I would recommend getting hold of the jar file for
the library and use [lein-localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo). Using this plugin you should be able to install the jar file in your local repo and use it from lein. This will require using (:impor ...) and Clojure Java interop of course.

Comment: Thanks. I was intimidated from the execution section. Your answer was iluminating. No need to download the jar files, I just added the maven repository to :repositories key